# How to add attributes to writeAttributeNS with PHP XMLWriter

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I'm newbie in XML-writer.
Any idea how to generate this with PHP XMLWriter

```
<definitions xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport">
```

I've done this already

```
$writer->startElement('definitions');
$writer->writeAttributeNS('xmlns','tns', null,'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport');
$writer->writeAttributeNS('xmlns',null, null, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/');
$writer->writeAttributeNS('targetNamespace', null, null, 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport');
```

But I get this "Warning: XMLWriter::writeAttributeNs(): Invalid Attribute Name in" 3'rd and 4'th lines

Thanks already!
JM

Answer (score 4):

Here is only one "normal" attribute in your xml. An this is the targetNamespace attribute. The other two are namespace (prefix) definitions

The `xmlns` attribute is the default namespace definition for the element and its child elements. It will be created automatically if you use `startElementNS()`.

The `targetNamespace` attribute has no namespace and can be set using `writeAttribute()`.

Last `xmlns:tns` is not needed in the example, it defines the namespace prefix "tns" for child elements and attibutes. Here is no element or attribute that uses it. If you add it with `setAttributeNS()`, XMLWriter will add the xmlns namespace, too. This is a reserved namespace (and namespace prefix). It is builtin into XML parsers and does not need to be defined, but it can.

```
$writer = new XMLWriter;
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$writer->startElementNS(
  NULL,
  'definitions',
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
);
  $writer->writeAttribute(
    'targetNamespace',
    'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport'
  );
  $writer->writeAttributeNS(
    'xmlns',
    'tns',
    'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
    'urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport'
  );
$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/SalesOrderImport" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
```

Here is an example for a namespace attribute, like with `startElementNS()` the namespace definition will be added automatically:

```
$writer->startElement('element');
  $writer->writeAttributeNS(
    'prefix',
    'attr',
    'urn:example:namespace',
    'value'
  );
$writer->endElement();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element prefix:attr="value" xmlns:prefix="urn:example:namespace"/>
```